# Oversized main screen overlapping on secondary screen - clean Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 20.04

My main monitor is on the left and my secondary one -flipped 90 degrees to the right- is on the right. When I setup my secondary monitor in system parameters this is what happens. **My primary monitor become some stretched out super landscape version of itself that pans when my cursor hits its borders to go into the second screen.**

[image: image of dual screen desktop]

The problem persists if both I put both screens in landscape.

[[image: image of dual landscape screen layout]

This is what I get from the `xrandr` command.

[[image: xrandr command results]

On top of that the second monitor is square (see first screenshot) although the setting is set to 1920x1080.

Any clues to how I can have my desktop look and act normal again in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well when I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. This isn't much of a solution, but I was able to switch from the proprietary NVIDIA drivers to the Nouveau drivers. Doing so allowed me to correctly configure my multi-screen layout (2 vertical, one portrait center display) in the display manager without any hiccups.

I do prefer the NVIDIA drivers, they seem to perform a bit better. That being the case, I re-test my setup with them every time I pull in updates. I just updated, and things improved marginally! Before the update, my center screen overlapped on both of my vertical screens. Now, my center screen only overlaps on one vertical screen. The other vertical screen works perfectly! If you do not have a tertiary monitor as I do, try using the NVIDIA drivers after pulling in the latest upgrades, it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with **20.04** and (new) **Samsung U32R590C** (UHD, curved) monitor.

---

Try changing the resolution (in Nvidia settings), from auto to the correct resolution. This should remove the 'pan' feature, so that 'current' (in xrandr) is actually **1920x1080** ..

**Note:** *still testing this, and trying to save/retain this fix.*

Answer (score -1):

Analyze the EDID results along the path `/sys/class/drm`.

```
ls /sys/class/drm/
version
```

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
error initialising realmode interface
do you have full superuser (root) permissions?
I'm sorry nothing was successful. Maybe try some other arguments
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvreo.png)