# Nvidia Video Driver Can't Play Full-Screen after Ubuntu 20.04 Upgrade (UPDATED)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, video

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 (LTS).  But now I can't play full-screen videos, whether from web browser of even VLC.  Whenever I select fullscreen video.  It creates  "picture in picture" effect in the upper left hand corner, screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKaWq.jpg

My machine is a win10 dual boot, Acre Aspire 5.  The output of `sudo lshw -C video` is

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:131 memory:6012000000-6012ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce MX350]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:50000000-50ffffff memory:6000000000-600fffffff memory:6010000000-6011ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
```

Installed Ubuntu drivers
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTXxx.png

***UPDATE 1***

The seems to be a bug in the 18.04 to 20.04 update that "prevents" the installation of some key drivers / software.

1.) using `ubuntu-drivers devices` to figure out what driver was missing and (recommended)...

2.) then using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Which actually FAILED.... with the following error:

```
Setting up linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.18build1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-extra-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-450:i386 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-450 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libnvidia-gl-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-450:i386 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-450:i386 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic (= 5.4.0-48.52); however:
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-450:amd64 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 (450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450:
 nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (<= 450.66-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not installed.
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 which provides nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (>= 450.66); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not installed.
  Package linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 which provides nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=5fc4b948-a7d5-454c-a0d8-7160f260d09f)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-48-generic
 linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04
 nvidia-driver-450
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However, I was able to immediately fix it using the same solution to the problem of not being able to install shutter.

The answer is [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Once I did this, I was able to finish the installation of the correct nvidia driver, rebooted, and verified that it was installed in "softwatre & updates"....

After all this... SAME PROBLEM... this is definitely an Ubuntu 20.04 bug..  had 18.04 on this machine... no problems.  The result of `sudo lshw -C video` is still `display: UNKNOWN`

**Update 2**

I went back and tried ALL of the suggested solutions by @hyttysmyrkky listed below.  And NONE of them worked.  The result of `sudo lshw -C video` is ALWAYS `display: UNKNOWN` .  FYI, this includes using the -47 kernel and the 440.100 driver.  NONE of the solutions worked, Same picture in picture, fullscreen mode problem. In addition to this error, under 20.04 I had the following problems:

1.)  Unable to power off my machine from system menu.  Screen goes dark, but the shut-down process would literally just hang no matter how long I waited, finally required a hard shutdown of holding the power button.

2.) The recognition of my intel wifi card was hit or miss at boot time.  If failed, I needed to re-boot to in order get wifi working because restarting network-manager had zero effect

3.) on a very annoyingly frequent basis, at boot my I would receive MOK messages (machine owner key) messages asking me to select boot systems even before grub.  This would happen no matter how many times I had previously done the same thing.

4.) Often the bios settings would revert to system defaults, completely bypassing grub and loading win10, which created the need to: 1.) re-boot windows in safe mode, 2.) enter bios change "sata settings" to from "RAID with array" to "AHCI", disable fast boot, 3) Log back into Win10 turn off safe mode and re-boot.  (i.e. giant waste of time)

I finally "fixed" the problem, by reverting back to 18.04 in which the "manually installed driver" option seems to work perfectly with the nvidia driver.  20.04 is "eye-candy", but I will wait year before attempting to upgrade again. Just switched to the NVIDIA-driver-450-server on 18.04 and it too works perfectly.

Comment: The `UNCLAIMED` indicator in `lshw` may be an indicator that a proper driver is not installed for the NVIDIA card.

Comment: This a pic of the installed drivers https://i.imgur.com/I9eXDSd.png

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I just updated the post above.  I went back and installed the correct driver, but end up with the same exact problem.

Comment: Temporary workaround: change from auto for resolution .. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239950/oversized-main-screen-overlapping-on-secondary-screen-clean-ubuntu-20-04-insta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nvidia-driver-450 successfully installed, this may not be related, but I'll let you know anyway: There seems to be some problem with Ubuntu 20 with its recent kernel update (from 5.4.0-47 to 5.4.0-48) with Nvidia drivers:

- [NVIDIA Driver Suddenly Failed (20.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277765/nvidia-driver-suddenly-failed-20-04-lts) (there may be a fix here)

The problem is also reported here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076302/problems-when-starting-ubuntu-20-04-on-the-kernel-5-4-0-48-generic
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-no-longer-loading-on-ubuntu-20-04/155128

(I had to switch back to kernel 5.4.0-47 and Nvidia driver 440.100 (as reported by `nvidia-smi` because Ubuntu shows no version but only "manually installed driver" for some reason) for now.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I updated my question above.  20.04 just doesn't seem market ready.